# Агрегаторы платежных систем в ру сегменте работающие с ип и физ лицами

Tags: интернет-магазин, платежи

Всегда пользовался robokassa.ru. Но со вчерашнего дня они перестали работать с физ лицами и ип.

Какие аналоги в ру сегменте вы можете посоветовать. Стабильные, с выгодными процентами, хорошей документацией для интеграции и возможностью работы в физ. лицами и ип.

Спасибо

Comment: прежде чем задавать вопросы прочитайте о том, [какие вопросы можно задавать на данном сайте](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Нашел вот такую интересную статью на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/company/web_payment_ru/blog/265349/), в ней все подробно расписано.

Для себя выбрал free-kassa.ru, потому что у них есть упрощенная интеграция для тех, кто переходит с robokassa.ru. Надо поменять id магазина, action в форме и секретные пароли - [линк](http://www.free-kassa.ru/docs/api.php#robokassa)